# How to repeat a column in a csv file using panda in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to repeat a column in a csv file 15 times using dataframe.  The file has a column of dates and a column of numbers.  I want each number in the second column repeated in that row another 15 times for each row with a date.

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(obs_sum_shift)-16):
    temp.append(obs_sum_shift[0].values[i:i+16])

obs_sum_shift_16 = pd.DataFrame(temp,index=obs_sum_shift.index[:-16])
```

```
GMT 0   1   2   3
1/2/1985 0:00   0   0   0   0.00206
1/2/1985 6:00   0   0   0.00206 0
1/2/1985 12:00  0   0.00206 0   0
1/2/1985 18:00  0.00206 0   0   0
```

This is a piece of what the code above does.  I want it to simply repeat the value if column 1 15 more time but in the same row.  This only shows columns 0 to 4 but there are actually columns from 1 to 15.

```
GMT 0   1   2   3
1/2/1985 0:00   0   0   0   0 
1/2/1985 6:00   0   0   0   0
1/2/1985 12:00  0   0   0   0
1/2/1985 18:00  0.00206 0.00206 0.00206 0.00206
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"GMT": ["1/2/1985 0:00", "1/2/1985 06:00", "1/2/1985 12:00"],
                  "0": [0, 0, 0.00206],
                  "1": [0, 0, 0.00206],
                  "2": [0, 0, 0.00206]})
```

So the idea is to create a new dataframe `df1` that simply repeats the first column `n` times. Then transpose this dataframe and `concat` it to your original dataframe.

```
n = 12
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df["0"] for _ in range(n)).T
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

**Edit:**

Using the example in the comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"GMT Russian": ["1/1/1985 6:00",
                                   "1/1/1985 12:00",
                                   "1/1/1985 18:00",
                                   "1/2/1985 0:00",
                                   "1/2/1985 6:00",
                                   "1/2/1985 12:00",
                                   "1/2/1985 18:00",
                                   "1/3/1985 0:00",
                                   "1/3/1985 6:00",
                                   "1/3/1985 12:00",
                                   "1/3/1985 18:00"],
                   1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00206, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
df.set_index("GMT Russian", inplace=True)

df.shape    # (11, 1)
```

Now, following the same procedure that I outlined above:

```
n = 15
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[1] for _ in range(n)).T
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)

df2.shape    # (11, 16)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I asked this question properly.  Let me try again.  I actually have a csv file with date time and single value in column 1.GMT Russian
1/1/1985 6:00 0
1/1/1985 12:00 0
1/1/1985 18:00 0
1/2/1985 0:00 0
1/2/1985 6:00 0
1/2/1985 12:00 0
1/2/1985 18:00 0.00206
1/3/1985 0:00 0
1/3/1985 6:00 0
1/3/1985 12:00 0
1/3/1985 18:00 0
This is a small piece of the csv file.  There are 23,920 rows.  I just want to repeat the single values shown in column 1 15 more times in the same row for all rows.  Thanks.

Comment: @dreynolds109 And the final output shape you want is going to be 23,920 rows and 16 columns (including original column 1)? Or 1 long column that is 23920*15=358800 rows long?

Comment: 23,920 rows with 16 columns.

Comment: @dreynolds109 See my latest edit. Of course I only have 11 rows, as per your provided data, but `df2` will end up with shape (23920, 16) when applied to your data.